# Reading each line of different data types from text file

Tags: java

I have a text file that provides information for 22 golf courses, including name of course, name, location, designer, greens fee, par, year built, and total yards. As I read in, each line needs to be stored to the appropriate variable and then used to create a few objects. The first line of the file is the number of golf courses in the text file.

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "\\GolfCourses.txt");
    //use file
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    //read input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    Tree newTree = new Tree();


    try{
         String line = br.readLine();
          if(line==null)
             throw new IOException();

        int clubs = Integer.parseInt(line);
        for(int i = 0; i < clubs; i++){
            String name = br.readLine();
            String location = br.readLine();
            double fee = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            int par = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String designer = br.readLine();
            int built = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int yards = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            newTree.insert(new TreeNode(new GolfCourse(name, location, designer, fee, par, built, yards))); 
        }

        in.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The read-in seems to jump ahead of itself, so the program is trying to parse strings instead of numbers. I've never had this problem before so I'm lost on how to fix it.

EDIT: The code is now working as intended. The issue was coming from the "i <= clubs" piece of the for loop. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your first `br.readLine()` would get your first line from the file, which is number of clubs. After the `if` statement, which fails, you are calling `br.readLine()`. This call would get the next line, as the first line was already retrived in the last call to `br.realLine()` in the `if` statement.

Try this:

```
String line = br.readLine();
if(line == null) {
    throw new IOException();
}
int clubs = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same "NumberFormatException" error. It happens right after the first line of the file is read.

EDIT: I'm not even getting through the first course.

Comment: @user1303995 is your first line in the text is a number, its imposiible to get NFE when doing parseInt.

Comment: @chaitanya10:  Stranger things have happened...it's possible to get an NFE if the number is larger than 2^32-1.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not try to parse line--was attempting to parse the next line. I now have a NullPointer error where I attempt to parse the double. Perhaps there is something I've missed when it comes to parsing a double?

Comment: @user1303995 can you post the stack trace please and the updated code pls.

Comment: @Makoto ahh, true that mate :).. +1 for your comment .. :)

Comment: @chaitanya10 I don't believe I know where to get the stack trace from. EDIT: turns out I don't know how to post the updated code as well... my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

**Read the file like this:**

```
File f = new File("Path");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

**Retriving of Fields:**

**If the fields like golf courses, name, locations are on a single line separated by "single space" for each entry:**

**-** Use `split(" ");`

**If the fields like golf courses, name, locations one per each line:**

**-** Use `split("\n");`   `Not "\\" but "\"`

**-** Use `for-loop` with `count of 8`, so to get 8 fields.

**Creation of Object:**

**-** Create a `Java bean` with 8 fields, to hold these values.

Comment: A POJO would be more advisable in this scenario as they're not working with Spring.

Comment: @Makoto I mentioned `Java Bean` **Not** `JEE Bean`, there is a difference between them.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra as far as the for loop you're suggesting, I would be making a nested for loop, correct? The outside of 22 iterations and the inside of 8?